# Retrieve Records from getTableQuery in a Custom Resource for Dynamic Table Data Display in FilamentPHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

How can I retrieve the record ID inside the `getTableQuery` method in a custom resource in filamentPHP, so that I can dynamically display table data based on this record? Specifically, I have the following custom action:

```php
Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()
    ->url(fn (Container $record): string => ContainerResource::getUrl('listOrders', ['record' => $record]))
```

And I want to use the retrieved record ID in the `where` clause of the `getTableQuery` as shown below:

```php
$query = Order::join('containers', 'orders.container_id', '=', 'containers.container_id')
    ->where('orders.container_id', /* I need to insert the record ID here, but how can I get it? */);
```

Note: The custom resource is for a system that manages orders and containers, and I want to list orders for a specific container based on the record ID retrieved from the URL when editing a container.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this inside the form function :
`$record = $form->getRecord();`